# date filter query not woking

Tags: sql

```
@SQL = "SELECT * from User WHERE LoginDate Between '2019-10-21' AND '2019-10-31'"
```

how can I add Date range in this query?

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: What is the error ? Maybe there is something with date formats... Also, do you know what database do you use ?

Comment: its show syntax error in date may be due to single quotes before select and last?

Comment: More code please.  I can't tell how you are using the code you posted, or how HTML and CSS are involved.  Also, what RDBMS?

Comment: Hi @Ali Raza, we need to know you database. Is it Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer or something else... Also can you show us one date data from the column `LoginDate`. Thanks!

Comment: Complete code here

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
 @SQL = "SELECT * from User WHERE LoginDate >= '2019-10-21' AND  LoginDate <= '2019-10-31'"
```